# problemas com o __dirname no electron js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron

eu estou fazendo um curso que usa electron 5.0.13, e esta dando esse erro no terminal da minha aplicação em electron

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined
at eval (index.js?bdb9:4)
at Object../node_modules/electron/index.js (chunk-vendors.js:2080)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
at fn (app.js:151)
at eval (cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/components/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&:2)
at Module../node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/components/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (app.js:950)
at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
at fn (app.js:151)
at eval (Home.vue?59e2:1)
at Module../src/components/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (app.js:1113)
```

eu estava usando electron 9.0 e me deparei com esse erro
no curso teve alguem que perguntou e o professor respondeu que era para colocar o electron 5.0.13, foi o que eu fiz, mas n resolveu, ja removi o yarn-lock e o node_modules varias vezes e não resolveu.

ta aqui o codigo

```html
<script src="https://electron.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<template>
    <v-content fluid>
        <v-form>
            <v-file-input multiple chips v-model="files" append-icon="mdi-send"
            label="Selecione um Legenda" prepend-icon="mdi-message-text"
            @click:append="processSubtitles"/>
        </v-form>
        <div class="pills">
            <Pill v-for="word in groupedWords" :key="word.name" 
            :name="word.name" :amount="word.amount"/>
        </div>
    </v-content>
</template>

<script>
import { ipcRenderer } from 'electron'
import Pill from './pill.vue'

export default {
    components: { Pill },
    data: function() {
        return {
            files: [],
            groupedWords: [
                { name: 'i', amount: 1234 },
                { name: 'you', amount: 900 },
                { name: 'he', amount: 853 }
            ]
        }
    },
     methods: {
         processSubtitles() {
             console.log(this.files)
            
            ipcRenderer.send('blabla', 'ping')
            ipcRenderer.on('blabla', (event, resp) => {
                console.log(resp)
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Quando você criou o BrowserWindow, você setou a flag webPreferences.nodeIntegration para true?

Comment: não setei não, só fui fazendo

Comment: Provavelmente, é esse o problema. Quando você cria o BrowserWindow, precisa setar esta flag para true, pois o erro aparentemente está no Vue. Porém, antes de setar essa flag, recomendo ler a documentação e avaliar se a sua aplicação não terá nenhum risco de segurança.

Answer (score 1):

Cria um arquivo chamado `vue.config.js` na raiz do projeto, e coloca isso dentro para habilitar a integração do Node.

```
module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  }
}
```

Creditos:
https://github.com/nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/issues/683#issuecomment-600179004

Comment: Não é recomendado utilizar `nodeIntegration: true`, tanto que ele vem desativado por padrão. Uma alternativa melhor envolve o uso do _preload_, por exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta usar a solução que tem [nessa publicação do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63615355/how-to-import-ipcrenderer-in-vue-js-dirname-is-not-defined) utilizando preload.js e `window`:

Dessa forma dá pra chamar o método abaixo dentro dos arquivos vue

```
window.ipcRenderer.send(channel, args...) .
```

Só tenha certeza de configurar o arquivo preload.js no vue.config.js:

```
// vue.config.js - project root
module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
       preload: 'src/preload.js'  //adicione essa linha
    }
  }
}
```

O arquivo preload.js:

```
// src/preload.js

import { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } from 'electron'


contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('ipcRenderer', {
  send: (channel, data) => {
    let validChannels = ['nameOfClientChannel'] // <-- Array of all 
    ipcRenderer Channels used in the client
    if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
      ipcRenderer.send(channel, data)
    }
  },
  receive: (channel, func) => {
    let validChannels = ['nameOfElectronChannel'] // <-- Array of all 
    ipcMain Channels used in the electron
    if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
      // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`
      ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args))
    }
  }
})
```

---

Outra solução pode ser encontrada [nesse artigo](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-safely-set-up-an-electron-app-with-vue-and-webpack-556fb491b83):

Ela usa um parâmetro __static ao invés __dirname para se referenciar ao arquivo preload.js e não configura no vue.config.js. Para ter certeza que funciona precisa desabilitar o warning do es-lint para o preload.js dentro do construtor do BrowserWindow:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
preload: path.resolve(__static, 'preload.js')
```

E tenha certeza que adicionou o arquivo preload.js dentro da pasta /public